# Get values of Input[type=(type)] from specific class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that does not work:

```
kw _class = _keyword1;
var text = $("'input." +  kw_class  + "[type=text]'").val();
var val =  $("'input." +  kw_class  + "[type=hidden]'").val();
```

Firefox console comes out with this:

```
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'input._keyword1[type=text]'
```

I have tried at least three combos of this that are not working that I found from other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because you have ' ' inside of the selector. It should be:

```
var text = $("input." +  kw_class  + "[type=text]").val();
var val =  $("input." +  kw_class  + "[type=hidden]").val();
```

Comment: Oops.  thanks!  It's always the small things.

Answer (score 2):

you have extra `''` in the selector

```
var text = $('input.' +  kw_class  + '[type=text]').val();
var val =  $('input.' +  kw_class  + '[type=hidden]').val();
```